# .net Swagger model schema is empty - only for GET formed by UNION

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

.net Swagger model schema is empty only for GET formed by UNION (a simple GET shows the right model schema)

How could I show a good model schema for the method swagger shows an empty schema?

EMPTY schema:
[image]

GOOD schema:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **SwaggerResponse**  like this one:

```
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "List of customers", typeof(IEnumerable<int>))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(BadRequestErrorMessageResult))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Type = typeof(NotFoundResult))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        if (id > 0)
            return Ok(new int[] { 1, 2 });
        else if (id == 0)
            return NotFound();
        else
            return BadRequest("id must be greater than 0");
    }
```

The difference between yours is that one uses HttpResponseMessage

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem was observed by @HelderSepu , the response I sent was not IEnumerable (because of the "Select" in Linq).

1. So I needed to create a model class, in order to have the right model schema:

   ```
   namespace SupplierB_api.Models { 
     public class SupplierResponse    {
       public int SupplierID;
       public string SupplierName;
       public char SupplierType;    } 
   }
   ```
2. Then, I use the model in Linq:

   ```
               var SuppliersDistributor = entities.tblD.Take(5).AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(d => new SupplierResponse { SupplierID = d.distributor_id, SupplierName = d.distributor_name, SupplierType = 'D'});

               var SuppliersPublisher = entities.tblN.Take(5).AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(p => new SupplierResponse { SupplierID = p.publisher_id, SupplierName = p.publisher_name, SupplierType = 'P' });
   ```
3. Then, I use SwaggerResponse (as suggested by @HelderSepu):

   ```
   [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "response", typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<SupplierResponse>))]
   ```